# SQL query to get time in each status

Tags: mysql

Given a table that looks like this

```
 
  |date      |From       | To                 |
  |01/01/21  |Open       |In progress         |
  |01/03/21  |In progress|In review           | 
  |01/10/21  |In Review  |Done                |
  |01/15/21  |Done       |Resolved            |
```

Is there a way to track the time spent in each status based on the date of the status change?
I only have one date column in the table I am working with.

The desired result would look something like this

```
|Time spent in phase|Status|
|2                  |Open
|7                  |In review
|5                  |Done
```

I have only one table to work with so is there any query that would work well for this? This workflow has set rules, so only open can go to in progress.

If so is it possible to use these workflow status changes to get a potential query?

Comment: BTW:  `date`,`from` and `to` are in the list of [reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-T) and it should be avoided to used these as column names.   And, also, you should have posted the query you tried to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: How do you get 5 days on Open from your data. the data move from open to inprogress (rows 1 and 2) in 2 days? Does open mean any status until done in which case thats 14 days? nb to column isn't helpful. ALSO what version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Do show what your desired results look like

Comment: Your desired result makes no sense.  the list under `status` should be `Open,In progress,In Review`, or `In progress,In review,Done`.  Currently you are skipping the status 'In progress'.

Answer (score 1):

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=206998168962b1d06ef310c6bc03e8f5)

Despite my last comment on your 'question', I created a fiddle. It has two options:

- Option1

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(COALESCE(LEAD(`Date`) OVER (ORDER BY `Date`),`date`),`Date`) as 'Time spent in phase',
    `From`
FROM ThatLooksLikethis;
```

output:

| Time spent in phase | From |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Open |
| 7 | In progress |
| 5 | In review |
| 0 | Done |

- Option2:

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(`Date`,COALESCE(LAG(`Date`) OVER (ORDER BY `Date`),`date`)) as 'Time spent in phase',
    `From`
FROM ThatLooksLikethis;
```

output:

| Time spent in phase | From |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Open |
| 2 | In progress |
| 7 | In review |
| 5 | Done |

P.S. this answer is using the MySQL 8.0 functions [LEAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead) and [LAG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag). If you are not using MySQL 8.0, but an older version then this answer might be useless....